# Issue while adding datasource to the project in Mosaic Decisions

Tags: mysql, datasource, data-access, mosaic-decisions

I want to use a dataset of MySQL Source that has been published by another user in Mosaic.

But when I try to add it to my Project, it says **"you do not have access to the selected datasource".**

**How can I access this datasource?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the required data source has been published as a private data source. You can check for a **small lock icon** against the data source name would indicate it being a **private**.

[image]

In order to get access to such data source please follow below steps -

1. Click on `Explore` button that will open a `Info page` of the selected source.
2. Click on `Request` tab right beside the `Info` tab.
3. Here you can select either you want permission for a particular **user** or a **group**; Need of the data source and then submit

[image]

[image]

4. Once the owner (publisher) of the data source grants the access, you can add it to your project and use it into the flows